# Access USB device storage via terminal

Tags: command-line, terminal, mount, usb, storage

For some reasons my Debian is broken and boots into a terminal based UI instead of the desktop.

Where can I find my USB device storage directory in this terminal?

Edit: It's not under `/media`.

Comment: Do you want assistance getting the GUI (graphical interface) to work, or assistance with accessing the USB device?

Comment: Just accesing the USB device directory in terminal. I don't know where it's directory located to find and explore it in terminal.

Comment: It could be under `/media`, but it might not get automatically mounted - update your question if not.

Comment: It's not under /media :(  how can I mount it?

Comment: I have mount it and it works fine now, tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments it must be under `/media` directory but it isn't, cause it's not mounted.

It's possible to mount USB drive in the following way:

```
sudo mkdir /media/usb-drive

sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb-drive/
```